# Generalized inverse of 2 x 2 block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices

I am reading Matrix Algebra - Theory, Computations, and Applications in Statistics by James E. Gentle (2007), and I am stuck on an exercise to show that the expression (3.165, p.101) below for a generalized inverse of a partitioned matrix is correct:

[image]

This seems similar in form to [the inverse of the partitioned matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion), but in this case, there are no restrictions mentioned on A or the partitioned matrices, so A could be non-square.

EDIT: A generalized inverse $A^-$ here refers to any matrix such that $AA^-A = A$

EDIT: Added full name of text and author

---

I tried but I am unable to extend the derivation of the square partitioned inverse case to this generalized case. I have also tried applying the given expression (3.165) to a simple matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 4 \\
    2 & 5 \\
    3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}

and obtained a matrix that does not seem to be the generalized inverse (In this case I take $A_{11}$ as the 2$\times$1 matrix):

\begin{bmatrix}
    -0.5 & 1.166667 & 0.5 \\
    -1 & 0.25 & -0.416667
\end{bmatrix}

Is there something I'm missing here, and is there a simple solution to show that the expression is the generalized inverse?

Comment: What is a "generalized inverse" (and in which ring are we working)?

Comment: @dan_fulea I'm not too familiar with the concept of rings, but in this context generalized inverse $A^−$ is any matrix such that $AA^−A=A^–$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no access to the source, and searching for Gentle Matrix Algebra delivers many Gentle Introduction to Matrix Algebra entries...

So i will use the setting from 
[Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)
which seems to be similar, but the notation differs.

---

Let us do some  computations, but of course in a setting without indices. Let 
$$
\begin{aligned}
M&=
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\ C & D
\end{bmatrix}\text{ be a partitioned matrix, associate then}
\\
Z &:= D-CA^-B\ ,\text{ and inductively on block shape}\\
M^-&:=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
A^- + A^-BZ^-CA^- & -A^-BZ^- \\\hline
-Z^-CA^- & Z^-
\end{array}
\right]
\ .\text{ Then we have:}
\\[3mm]
MM^-
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\ C & D
\end{bmatrix}
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
A^- + A^-BZ^-CA^- & -A^-BZ^- \\\hline
-Z^-CA^- & Z^-
\end{array}
\right]
\\
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
AA^- - (I-AA^-)BZ^-CA^- & (I-AA^-)BZ^- \\\hline
CA^- - (D-CA^-B)Z^-CA^- & (D-CA^-B)Z^-
\end{array}
\right]
\\
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
AA^- - (I-AA^-)BZ^-CA^- & (I-AA^-)BZ^- \\\hline
CA^- - ZZ^-CA^- & ZZ^-
\end{array}
\right]
\ ,
\\
N:=MM^-M
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
AA^- - (I-AA^-)BZ^-CA^- & (I-AA^-)BZ^- \\\hline
CA^- - ZZ^-CA^- & ZZ^-
\end{array}
\right]
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\ C & D
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&\text{ has then the entries}
\\[3mm]
N_{11}
&=
AA^-A - (I-AA^-)BZ^-CA^-A \\
&\qquad\qquad + (I-AA^-)BZ^-C
 \\
&=A + (I-AA^-)BZ^-C(I-A^-A)\ ,\\[3mm]
N_{12}
&=AA^-B - (I-AA^-)BZ^-CA^-B \\
&\qquad\qquad
+ (I-AA^-)BZ^-D\\
&=AA^-B + (I-AA^-)BZ^-Z\ ,\\[3mm]
N_{21}
&= CA^-A - ZZ^-CA^-A \\
&\qquad\qquad+
 ZZ^-C\\
&= CA^-A + ZZ^-C(I-A^-A)\ ,\\[3mm]
N_{22}
&= CA^-B - ZZ^-CA^-B \\
&\qquad\qquad+
 ZZ^-D\\
&= CA^-B + ZZ^-(D-CA^-B)\\
&= CA^-B + ZZ^-Z\\
&= CA^-B + Z\\
&= D\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

So only the value $D$ is guaranteed. (Note that the value $I$ corresponds to two the one or each other identity matrix, such that $IB$, resp. $CI$ make sense.) We need more. There are some properties that can be used, but i could not find something to have a better comparison. (Please compare the above entries in $N$ with the four entries $A,B,C,D$ in $M$, building the difference. Some (non-commutative) factors occur, and sufficient conditions can be stated, but these are very restrictive for the given generality of the question.)

---

I was searching for a simple counterexample, so here is my first quick try.

The relation $MM^-M=M$ can not work in general (with my choices of minus-elements, alias generalized matrices.) For this, take $A=0$ (in some block dimension) and $D=0$ (in an other one), so $Z=0$, my choices are then $A^-=0$, $Z^-=0$ (of transposed shapes). Then we compute
$$
MM^-M
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & B\\ C & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & B\\ C & 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\ ,
$$
which is not $M$ with a high statistical confidence. 
This was a special case, i know it is not fair to restrict to such a special choice, which is humanly generated. But in the general case we have a very good statistics for the formula.

Comment: Thanks for working this out! I am inclined to accept this answer, but let me think about this for awhile first, since the book and the other answer mentioned that the given expression can be shown to be the generalized inverse.

I will add more details about the book. Also, the context is that A (and all matrices) have real elements (i.e. $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$), so that is the same setting in [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)

Comment: Please let the issue a longer time open, when accepting an answer readers tend to lose interest and not even read the question, except for the case that the question was found for the reason of an explicit search by key words. I posted the answer to show my problems with the generalized inverse. (It is sometimes useful in the framework of operator algebras for similar reasons as it is in connection with solving equations.) I only want to see if the given counterexample is rejected by some assumptions in the book, or if $A^-$ is a "special" generalized inverse.

Comment: Ok, will keep this open for awhile then. I believe your counterexample is valid, as I could not find any other assumptions in the book. Also don't think $A^-$ is special, it was stated in the book as a general version of the Moore Penrose Inverse that only has to meet the first condition of $AA^-A=A$.

Answer (score 2):

Gentle is using the notation $A^-$ to refer to a generalized inverse of the matrix $A$. This means that $A^-$ can be any matrix satisfying the equation $AA^-A=A$. You can verify the given formula by multiplying $AA^-A$ and checking that this is equal to $A$.

At the bottom of page 97, Gentle writes

> Without additional restrictions on $A$, the generalized inverse is not unique.

So, the proposed formula will produce *a* generalized inverse, but there may be others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am trying to check that $AA^{-}A$ is indeed equal to $A$, but I am unable to reduce the long expression. Do you have any tips for this? Sorry if this is obvious as I'm not too familiar with the topic.

For example, if I let $A_{11}$ = $A$, $A_{12}$ = $B$, $A_{21}$ = $C$ and $A_{22}$ = $D$, I get the top left block as equal to $A + AA^{-}BZ^{-}CA^{-}A - BZ^{-}CA^{-}A - AA^{-}BZ^{-}C + BZ^{-}C$, which I can't show to be equal to $A$